# USE DATABASE efficiency

Tags: mysql, database

After analyzing, the project I wanted to needed to create more databases.

Question: is it good practice to build up 1000s of databases. Is it efficient?

For example. SQL COMMAND:

```
USE SOMEDATABASE;
```

What happens if I run this if total database on my server is 100. It shouldn't take that much of time.

But, what happens if I had to run the same command if there are 1000000 databases. Looks like it will reduce efficiency. So, is it the bad practice? Or should I need to contemplate moving these database into tables and building relationships?

Comment: "Or should I need to contemplate moving these database into tables and building relationships?" - erm , what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Millions of databases on a single MySQL server won't work.  Thousands is a very bad idea.

The big hosting services supporting php web apps (like WordPress, etc) handle hundreds of relatively small databases on a single server. But they expect their customers to do all the database creation and configuration work.

If these thousands of databases are for a particular single application, you will most likely be better off combining them into a single database with columns to indicate which user owns each row of information. That approach will perform better and will be cheaper to provision (add users, delete users, etc), back up, optimize, and otherwise maintain.

The one thing that could possibly DEMAND multiple databases is the need for rigid separation of one user's data from another's.